# Is Adobe Photoshop CS 5.1 compatible with Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs5, mac

I have Adobe Photoshop CS 5.1 installed on Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks), and it works just fine.  Does anyone know if this version of Photoshop will still work if I upgrade to Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)?

Comment: What tells the Homepage from Adobe about this? There should be a hint about that ...

Answer (score 1):

The comments on this blog post say CS 5.1 works fine on Yosemite: http://blogs.adobe.com/crawlspace/2014/10/photoshop-and-mac-osx-10-10-yosemite.html